# Does Kirby wear shoes or are those his bare feet?

Tags: kirby-series

[image: kirby]

Pretty simple question. Looking for evidence or reasoning either way.

Evidence from the TV show is also allowed.

Comment: Of course those are shoes! [Here is a picture of his real feet.](https://cdn2.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/8238617/kirby_feet.jpg)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [Kirby Wiki](http://kirby.wikia.com/wiki/Kirby), those are Kirby's feet:

> Kirby is a small pink spherical creature with two stubby arms, **two red feet**, and two oval-shaped eyes with black pupils

This is further backed up when comparing against different coloured Kirby:

> In general, members of the species all look similar, but sometimes have **different colored skin, eyes, and feet**

Given that Kirby has also been seen [sleeping in bed with his red feet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KQodO8R6AGg), I think it's a fair assessment to say that they are considered 'feet' not 'shoes':

[image: Kirby asleep in bed]

Answer (score -5):

Definitely his FEET here is my reasons

1. He doesn't take them off when he sleeps (but that could just be cause he's weird like that)
2. We would most likely be able to see where the shoes end
3. If they were shoes they would actually look like shoes and they don't look like shoes because if they were flats we would be able to see his skin and they don't look like any other type of shoes
4. His feet would probably look almost exactly the same under neath
    there you go 4 reasons that they are feet

Comment: 1) Not that we can see. But maybe he takes them off off-screen. 2) Why *wouldn't* he wear dark pink shoes? 3) They do look like shoes, drawn in a very simplistic style. That's why this question exists in the first place. 4. Kirby isn't a Waddle Dee though. And besides, they have the same foot/shoe coloring problem as Kirby, we don't know if they're wearing shoes.

Comment: 1) i never siad he WAS a waddle dee and 2) Why though why do you have to be like that?