# Is Toad's head a hat or part of the body?

Tags: mario-series

Watching a Paper Mario : Thousand Year Door Playthrough, and in it we can see toads that have their heads sewn like if it was a hat that was repaired.

I always tought the big thing in their head with the dots was part of their body, but this seems to point that it's more a piece of clothing than a part of their body.

Also, if it's a hat, have we ever seen a Toad without his hat?

EDIT: Picture
[image]

Comment: This seems to be very clearly a design-type question.

Comment: More seeing it as a lore question.

Comment: Similar question that was found to be ok here: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/303044/does-kirby-wear-shoes-or-are-those-his-bare-feet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this video](https://youtu.be/O0w6c566XGQ?t=36s), **it is a hat**.  They show a scene from the Super Mario Bros. Super Show where Toad is being flown away by some sort of dinosaur-like creature (forgive me if that's some sort of Mario character).  Toad manages to escape, and used his head piece as a parachute, thus revealing that it's really a hat, and not his head.

The [Mario Wiki](https://www.mariowiki.com/Toad_(species)#Super_Mario_RPG:_Legend_of_the_Seven_Stars) also references that this is a hat, under the *Super Mario RPG: Legend of the Seven Stars* section:

> Many Toads in this game have different patterns on **their hats** than normally found on Toads.

Even the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toad_(Nintendo)) for Toad has a picture of him with his Mushroom Cap/Hat removed, however it does mention that none of the games seem to confirm or deny this:

> Toad has on occasion removed his mushroom cap, revealing three strands of hair; however, the games have never confirmed or refuted this.

[image: Toad]

Comment: Seeing toad without his hat still makes me laugh every time I see it.

Comment: Some sources claim that the TV shows are not really canon.  Can you provide proof that they are?

Comment: @Mystagogue probably not - most sources that claim it's not a hat seem to be forums. I purposely avoided these sources since that aren't the most valid. Can you provide sources that otherwise suggest it isn't a hat? Can you provide sources that claim the TV show isn't canon?  This is merely just the information that I've found and reported.

Comment: @TimmyJim the mario wiki article on toads seems to be conflicted on this issue.  While the one section calls their cap a hat, other sections state that it is never explicitly confirmed or refuted that the cap is removable.

Comment: @Mystagogue so has the Wikipedia page on Toad as I've stated in my answer.